# Reading WordPress REST API JSON data via Ajax showing blank screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to pull data in my hybrid app through wordpress rest api. But I'm getting a blank screen. No error msg is thrown. Just a blank screen is coming. I have checked for syntactical error in lint and there's no error in code. I'm using the following code:

```
 var BASE_URI = "https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/smushbits.com/";
 var POST_OFFSET = 0;


 function load_post() {
 $.ajax({
 url: BASE_URI + "posts",
 type: "GET",
 dataType: "json",
 data: {
         "number": 10 ,
         "offset": POST_OFFSET
   },
   error: function() {
   alert("An error occured.");
    },
    success: function(response) {
    $.each(response, function(index, data) {
    $('<li><a href="#single" id="'+data.posts[index].ID+'"><h1>'+data.posts[index].title+'</h1><p>'+getDays(data.posts[index].date)+'</p></a></li>').appendTo('#latest-list');
     $(document).on("click", "#"+data.posts[index].ID, function() {
        get_single_post(data.posts[index].title, data.posts[index].date, data.posts[index].URL, data.posts[index].content);
          });
    });
   $('#latest-list').listview('refresh');
     }
  });
 POST_OFFSET+=10;
 }

  $(document).ready(function(){
   load_post();
  });
```

Demo: http://smushbits.com/smushbits/www

Comment: How to you call `load_post()`? and why there is a giant whitespace in `BASE_URI`?

Comment: use your browser console to check for errors. `data` isn't what you think it is inside the loop ... should just be using `data.ID` or `data.title`

Comment: @Zealander I've updated the code and also killed that giant whitespace.

Comment: @charlietfl The json is formatted that way. It contains details about different posts.

Comment: try to use jQuery instead of $ , may be beacuse of the jquery version , for example $(document) , jQuery(document)

Comment: @VishalSingh  `$.each(response.posts` .. then each item in loop is an object  .. `data.title` for example ... https://jsfiddle.net/epvecnfb/

Comment: @charlietfl It doesn't work for me. I am still getting the same blank annoying screen.

Comment: what errors are thrown?

Comment: @charlietfl No errors are thrown. Is there any logical error in my code?

Comment: create a demo with all the resources included that replicates your problem. Did you switch to method shown in demo I made that works?

Comment: @charlietfl here's a demo: http://smushbits.com/smushbits/www

Comment: need to use your browser console to look at errors. Your click handler isn't created properly and throws error